# How to load component conditionally in angular on button click

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm very new to Angular.

I want to load a child component conditionally within a component by clicking button. On button click, it should re-render the respective child component.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="onTabClick('0')">Transmit</button>
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="onTabClick('1')">Published</button>
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="onTabClick('2')">Bulk Transmit</button>
</div>
<div>
  <app-sports  *ngIf="tabIndex === 0"></app-sports>
  <app-movies  *ngIf="tabIndex === 2"></app-movies>
</div>
```

**TS file**

```
tabIndex = 2 ;


  onTabClick(index){
        this.tabIndex = index;
   }
```

Comment: You are passing string('0') and checking with a number 0, either make === to == or pass number on both sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have passed string as argument but checking numbers in tab. you can check on stackblitz link:

[check stackblitz link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wejvgq)

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="onTabClick(0)">Transmit</button>
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="onTabClick(1)">Published</button>
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="onTabClick(2)">Bulk Transmit</button>
</div>
<div>
  <app-sports  *ngIf="tabIndex === 0"></app-sports>
  <app-movies  *ngIf="tabIndex === 2"></app-movies>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 0,1,2 as string in the onTabClick(),  whereas in the .ts file you have tabIndex as integer.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing parameters 0,1,2 like strings and checking condition with `===`
it' also checking type (means sting or number)

Possible solutions:

1. place `==` instead of `===`
2. change argumens `'1'` to `1`, `'2'` to `2`